# Configure xscreensaver to use another program's screensaver?

Tags: screensaver, xscreensaver, boinc

I use Boinc for shared computing of Seti@Home. I would like to set the Boinc screensaver on my Ubuntu 14.04. For that I installed xscreensaver and I got the advice to

> add the following to the 'programs' preference in your .xscreensaver file:
>
> ```
> GL: boincscr -root \n\
> ```

Typing `which xscreensaver` gave me `/usr/bin/xscreensaver`. But I cannot find the `.xscreensaver` file `/bin` directory.

I typed in terminal `emacs xscreensaver` and a blank file opened. Could it be that I have to create it? Since I don't know how to do it, can I instead access another file and do the change there?

Comment: The file `.xscreensaver` should exist (or be created by you) in your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

in command line enter "sudo nano ~/.xscreensaver"

Comment: Thanks! I asked long ago, but I will give it try when I can. Welcome to the community!